# Why does Spring Data MongoDB not expose events for update…(…) methods?

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb, event-listener

It appears that the update for **mongoOperations** do not trigger the events in **AbstractMongoEventListener**.

[This post indicates that was at least the case in Nov 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913431/what-is-the-abstractmongoeventlistener-method-equivalent-for-updatemulti-mongoop?s=2%7C0.1557)

Is there currently any way to listen to update events like below?  This seems to be quite a big omission if it is the case.

```
MongoTemplate.updateMulti()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is no oversight. Events are designed around the lifecycle of a domain object or a document at least, which means they usually contain an instance of the domain object you're interested in.

Updates on the other hand are completely handled in the database. So there are no documents or even domain objects handled in `MongoTemplate`. Consider this basically the same way JPA `@EntityListener`s are only triggered for entities that are loaded into the persistence context in the first place, but not triggered when a query is executed as the execution of the query is happening in the database.

Comment: thanks for your comment but I still consider this an oversight.  Your comment that "Events are designed around the lifecycle of a domain object or a document at least" to me does not exclude updates, in which you refer to a domain object, by class, as in MongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, DomainObject.class, collectionName);  That implies that $update is a piece of a domain object, referencable by $query, and of type DomainObject.

Comment: Even if that does not exclude updates to you, the only way to implement that would basically subvert the efficiency of the update operation, as we'd have to read the document first, materialize ist, trigger events and then write it back. This completely subverts the intent of the update operation, which is supposed to be executed *in the database*. If you want the domain objects to be materialized, read them, change them and write them back. You can't have both at the same time. That's how databases (in this case MongoDB) works.

Comment: What about if the hypothetical update listener (onBeforeUpdate) just provided the query DBO and update DBO to the listener.  That would serve at least two use cases I'm thinking of.  First is staling an etag object (which is stored in another database), second is sending a webhook with updated state information.

Comment: Although I don't agree with the rationale, nor that a solution here [necessarily] has to subvert the efficiency of update(), this is the correct answer to my original question.

Comment: How does `@Version` handle this then ? When you call `mongoTemplate.updateFIrst(...)`, Spring Data Mongo adds `, "$inc" : { "version" : { "$numberLong" : "1" } }` to your query.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too late to answer this Question, I have the same situation with `MongoTemplate.findAndModify` method and the reason I needed events is for Auditing purpose. here is what i did.

1.EventPublisher (which is ofc MongoTemplate's methods)

```
public class CustomMongoTemplate extends MongoTemplate {

    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;


    @Autowired
    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher
                                                         applicationEventPublisher) {
        this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
    }

   //Default Constructor here

    @Override
    public <T> T findAndModify(Query query, Update update, Class<T> entityClass) {
        T result = super.findAndModify(query, update, entityClass);

        //Publishing Custom Event on findAndModify
        if(result!=null && result instanceof Parent)//All of my Domain class extends Parent
            this.applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new AfterFindAndModify
                    (this,((Parent)result).getId(),
                            result.getClass().toString())
            );

        return result;
    } }
```

2.Application Event

```
public class AfterFindAndModify extends ApplicationEvent {

    private DocumentAuditLog documentAuditLog;

    public AfterFindAndModify(Object source, String documentId,
                            String documentObject) {
        super(source);
        this.documentAuditLog = new DocumentAuditLog(documentId,
                documentObject,new Date(),"UPDATE");
    }

    public DocumentAuditLog getDocumentAuditLog() {
        return documentAuditLog;
    }
}
```

3.Application Listener

```
public class FindandUpdateMongoEventListner implements ApplicationListener<AfterFindAndModify> {

    @Autowired
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AfterFindAndModify event) {
        mongoOperations.save(event.getDocumentAuditLog());
    }
}
```

and then

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "my.pkg")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.pkg"})
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    //.....

    @Bean
    public FindandUpdateMongoEventListner findandUpdateMongoEventListner(){
        return new FindandUpdateMongoEventListner();
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to database changes, even the changes completely outside your program (MongoDB 4.2 and newer).

(code is in **kotlin** language. same for java)

```
@Autowired private lateinit var op: MongoTemplate

@PostConstruct
fun listenOnExternalChanges() {
    Thread {
        op.getCollection("Item").watch().onEach {
            if(it.updateDescription.updatedFields.containsKey("name")) {
                println("name changed on a document: ${it.updateDescription.updatedFields["name"]}")
            }
        }
    }.start()
}
```

This code only works when replication is enabled. You can enable it even when you have a single node:

Add the following replica set details to mongodb.conf (/etc/mongodb.conf or /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf or C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg) file

```
replication:
  replSetName: "local"
```

Restart mongo service, Then open mongo console and run this command:

```
rs.initiate()
```